# Prơblem with installation of OMNeT++

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-18.04, omnet++

The problem in omnetpp-5.4.1 installation.

I have successfully done the entire process of downloading OMNeT++. While writing OMNeT++ to enter into the IDE I am getting this error:

> An error has occurred. See the log file
>   /home/abc/MySoftwares/omnetpp-5.4.1/samples/.metadata/.log.

Comment: Have you configured and built OMNeT++?

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: Yes, I tried to run ./configure and make command. 
installation was successful and it was mentioned in the terminal to type omnetpp to open the ide. 
and when I wrote omnetpp. I got this error.

Comment: I am not very sure but I think there is some error because of the version of JAVA,

Answer (score 1):

Use OMNeT++ 5.5.1. Recent versions of debian updated java to version 11 which is not compatible with the Eclipse version in omnet 5.4.1.